# How do I get internet connection on new Debian installation

Tags: debian, networking, internet

I have two old Dell laptops on which I am trying to install Debian Buster 10.7 using a USB card with a freshly downloaded image from the Debian website. On one,a Latitude E6230, the process has worked fine. On the other, an Inspiron 14z, it seemed to have worked fine -- except that when I tried to use `apt-get` it turned out that there is no internet connection, in spite of the WiFi having apparently been successfully configured in the course of the installation, and there being an Ethernet cable plugged into the machine. (And I was able to successfully use WiFi and Ethernet with other machines -- the problem is not with my network).

`ip link show` gives me:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10000
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
2: wlp7s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
   link/ether a4:17:31:b1:fd:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I attempted `sudo ip link set wlp7s0 up` with no apparent effect.

If I run `lspci -knn |grep Net -A2` i get

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Dell AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0209]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
        Kernel modules: ath9k
```

I would like to get both the WiFi and the Ethernet working (and they were working on the machine before I tried installing Debian). Where do I go from here?

Comment: Looks like your wifi card is not detected by Debian. Try `ip link show` and see if your wifi card shows up there

Comment: `ip link show` gives me 
`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10000
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp7s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
  link/ether a4:17:31:b1:fd:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`
Not sure where to go from there....

Comment: Thanks @GAD3R , I've added the output.

Comment: `sudo dhclient wlp7s0` takes at least 30 seconds to run, but doesn't achieve anything I can see. `rfkill` is not found, and cannot be installed through `apt` because there is no network connection, so `Unable to locate package rfkill`

Comment: Try reloding the wifi module `sudo modprobe -rv ath9k` , `sudo modprobe -v ath9k` then `sudo dhclient wlp7s0`

Comment: For some reason after I do `sudo modprobe -rv ath9k`, the system `Cannot find device "wlp7s0"` and it is no longer detected by `ip link show`. :(

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe -v ath9k`